# how to get a displayField from an associated model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm new to CakePHP and I'm having troubles to get a display field of an associated model.

My model is something like this:
- Questions that hasMany Notes. 
- Notes belongsTo Questions and users.
- Users hasMany Notes.

Users have a field named name that is being used as displayField when I view a Note. But on de view method of the questions I only get user_id. Is there a way to get the name of the users associated to the notes of a certain Question?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the recursive parameter: [cakephp docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#retrieving-your-data)

```
$this->Question->recursive=1;
$questions=$this->Question->find('all');
$this->set(compact('questions'));
```

Then in your view:

```
  foreach($question['Note'] as $note)
        {
           foreach($note['User'] as $user){
            echo $user[name];
              }
           }
```

Code edited.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect, this was what I need. I actually add to use recursive=2

Comment: There is one usekess loop in my example. Types from my phone.

Comment: You shouldn't have to set recursive to 2 since you have a direct relation `Questions that hasMany Notes`, thus `recursive=1` should be sufficitent. It is not advised to use `recursive=2` especially for big datasets as it is slow due to the vast number of records that is being fetched.

Comment: I've no reputation to accept the answer for what I understand.

Comment: Borislav - but what I want is the user.name and the user as no direct relation to the Question, or am I seeing it wrong?